# Varieties are isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:Y\to X$ be a birational morphism, Y is projective. Let $H$ be a very general ample divisor on $Y$. If $f^{*}f_{*}H=H$, is it true that $Y$ is isomorphic to $X$?

Comment: What is your definition of $f_*H$?

Comment: Hi, Mohan, I mean the pushforward of H.

Comment: I know it is the push-forward, but in what sense? The most common method is to take $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y(H)$ and consider it as a coherent sheaf on $X$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It could be what Kollár likes to call the "birational transform". In this case I think you would just look at $f(H)$ and pray that it's a divisor.

Answer (score 2):

By $f^{*}f_{*}H=H$, there is no curve contracted by $f$. Hence $f$ is finite. If assume $X$ is normal, then this birational morphism must be an isomorphism by Zariski Main Theorem.